# How to handle GET params within urlManager's rule in Yii?

Tags: url, yii, get, parameters, yii-url-manager

I pass a query string to `SearchController::actionDefault` in form of `GET` parameter `q`:

`/search/?q=...`

However I need to define a rule that would automatically initialize this parameter with some value or define another param.

If I'll request `mysite.com/showall` I need get the same content like in `/search/?q=*`

This is what I've tried:

`'/showall'     => '/search/default/index/?r=*',`

Comment: You mean, that you need **one** rule where params will be passed with standard `get` syntax?

Comment: @PeterM Yes, just one static rule for one page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this!

there is possible to set defaultParams in urlManager, and finaly it looks like in application config file:

```
...
'components' => array(
    ...

    'urlManager' => array(
        ...
        'rules' => array(
            ....
            '/show_all' => array( '/search/default/index', 'defaultParams' => array('show_all'=>'-') ),
            ....
        ),
        ...
    ),
    ...
),
```

Comment: +1 This is usable in more situations and official documentation doesn't introduce it in any way. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer also works when you are getting different requests and you need to map it to the same `GET` param.

For example I want all of these requests:

- `user/pics`
- `user/photos`
- `user/pictures`

to actually generate: `user/index?content=photos`.

This might be one of a way to go:

```
'<controller:user>/(<content:photos>|pics|pictures)' => array('<controller>/index', 'defaultParams'=>array('content'=>'photos')),
```